# Mesa Installation: confiuguration process is ok but error in installation process

Tags: mesa

Hello i am a new user of ubuntu. I am trying to install mesa in ubuntu.The configuration process is ok.But when i am try to install, it shows this message

```
xmlconfig.c:34:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory
```

what will be the solutions of this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the build-essential package installed?